# Funnel query with Elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I'm trying to analyze a funnel using event data in Elasticsearch and have difficulties finding an efficient query to extract that data.

For example, in Elasticsearch I have:

```
timestamp          action        user id
---------          ------        -------
2015-05-05 12:00   homepage      1
2015-05-05 12:01   product page  1
2015-05-05 12:02   homepage      2
2015-05-05 12:03   checkout      1
```

I would like to extract the funnel statistics. For example:

```
homepage_count  product_page_count  checkout_count
--------------  ------------------  --------------
2             1                  1
```

Where homepage_count represent the distinct number of users who visited the homepage, product_page_count represents the distinct numbers of users who visited the homepage after visiting the homepage, and checkout_count represents the number of users who checked out after visiting the homepage and the product page.

What would be the best query to achieve that with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for the actions and then a [`cardinality` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) for the unique user count per action, like below. note that I've also added a `range` query in case you want to restrict the period to observe:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2021-06-01",
        "lte": "2021-06-07"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "actions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "action"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "users": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is a typical case where the [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) comes in handy. The implementation is a bit naive, but it shows you the basics of implementing a funnel.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "funnel": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": """
          state.users = new HashMap()
        """,
        "map_script": """
          def user = doc['user'].value.toString();
          def action = doc['action.keyword'].value;
          if (!state.users.containsKey(user)) {
            state.users[user] = [
              'homepage': false,
              'product': false,
              'checkout': false
            ];
          }
          state.users[user][action] = true;
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          return state.users;
        """,
        "reduce_script": """
          def global = [
            'homepage': 0,
            'product': 0,
            'checkout': 0
          ];
          def res = [];
          for (state in states) {
            for (user in state.keySet()) {
              if (state[user].homepage) global.homepage++;
              if (state[user].product) global.product++;
              if (state[user].checkout) global.checkout++;
            }
          }
          return global;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above aggregation will return exactly the numbers you expect, i.e.:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "funnel" : {
      "value" : {
        "product" : 1,
        "checkout" : 1,
        "homepage" : 2
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need users with relationship between actions. Like users who visited the homepage, users who visited the product page after visiting the homepage,  users who checked out after visiting the homepage and the product page.

Comment: You're right, I missed that part. See my updated answer which makes use of a custom scripted aggregation to compute the funnel as you expect.

Comment: This query looking great. But one thing I need more, we are not using timestamp here. I need users who performed events in order according to timestamp like product event should be performed after homepage then we can increment product event count to 1. Same for checkout event we can increment  checkout event count to 1 if user performed homepage and product event before checkout event.

Comment: Yes, as I told you, the logic is naive, but now that you know how you can achieve it, you can improve the logic to make it work the way you like ;-) This is not ES related anymore, it's pure business logic and only a matter of adding some more logic in the reduce script where you consolidate the user data from all shards.